Is there any limit on how long a travel agent can take to book a flight?
When one purchase is a flight ticket via an online travel agent, the online travel agent may take some time to process the booking and send the actual ticket to the customer. Is there any limit on how long that booking can be?
Assume that the customer can't cancel the booking, if that matters. I'd guess there must be limit to protect customers for excessively long processing time. I'm mostly interested in the United States, and I'm curious about other areas as well (online travel agents tend to be located anywhere).

Why would there be a rule? Nothing changes based on the processing.

@Tak because at some point, the passenger needs the ticket.

Well they have it before then.

@Tak not always. or the booking may eventually be unsuccessful after x days, when prices have doubled.

Do you have an example of this?

@Tak yes, eDreams.

I believe it used to be that travel agents were required to report sales to ARC/BSP by 11:59 PM on the next day. This meant that airlines would not know that a ticket was sold until that point (and agents could void a non-refundable ticket and they'd never know it ever existed). I don't know if that's still a thing.
